# Is VS 2010 SharePoint functionality good enough to replace WSP Builder?

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder

I have been using WSP builder up until now with VS 2008. I recently upgraded my IDE to VS 2010, and have heard that VS 2010 now includes functionality to work with MOSS directly.

If you guys have had any experience with this new MOSS functionality and have come from a WSP builder background I would like to hear what you think.

Just to add more focus to my question, I am not interested in ease of deployment at this stage, only the ability to wrap up a WSP package, so I can ship this off to production machines. So can VS 2010 out of the box create WSP packages from class library projects, like WSP Builder does?

Comment: You may be interested in authors blogpost: http://keutmann.blogspot.com/2009/11/sharepoint-2010-and-wspbuilder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, but for SharePoint 2010 only.
If you want to build solution for 2007, you'll still need WSPBuilder.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I just know that most of our customers will be using 2007 for the next 3 years, so this new functionality will have a lot of time to mature before I get to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used WSPBuilder to upgrade a solution that was done with WSP Builder and MOSS 2007 to 2010.  It worked beautifully.

That said, my stance is to use VS 2010 and the associated [toolkits](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) for NEW SP 2010 development.  WSPBuilder remains the king for all MOSS dev.

I would love to see Carsten and the CKSDev guys work together on this, but I don't know if that will ever happen... :-(